# Java - What are the vulnerabilities of a port-listening program?

Tags: java, security, networking, tcp, ports

I've recently created a fairly simple IRC client and server in Java but to make it fully functional I had to port forward. It occurred to me that there were probably some security issues with opening ports so I did some research. Everywhere, I found people saying that 'the biggest vulnerability is the program listening to the port'.

So my questions are:

1. What exactly can be exploited in a Java program which listens to a port and writes incoming data to a string?
2. As the developer of the software, how can I prevent these vulnerabilities?

Comment: +1 for wanting to avoid vulnerabilities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous ways an attacker can take advantage of a known open port ranging from exploiting bugs in TCP implementation, causing denial-of-service by tricking your server into performing expensive computation (remember recent [2.2250738585072012e-308 bug](http://www.exploringbinary.com/java-hangs-when-converting-2-2250738585072012e-308/)?), causing buffer overflows to crash your program or to even make it execute arbitrary code.

#### Platform security

There have been a few vulnerabilities in TCP implementation on some operating systems in which an attacker relied on knowing an open port on a target host, e.g. [SYN flood attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood). These have been largely mitigated in all major OSes out there, but whoever is responsible for the security of your host should be on a constant lookout for recent security issues in the platform.

#### Server security

Vulnerabilities in the OS and TCP implementation aside, there are also potential issues connected with the server itself. If your server can perform security-relevant operations in response to requests it receives, an attacker can take advantage of it. These include reading and writing files, allocating large chunks of memory, sending queries to databases etc.

#### From developer perspective

Ensuring that your server can run with low privileges and low resources, that it validates all input received from the user and escapes all output it sends to other systems and that it does not perform any unnecessary security-relevant actions are the first steps to making it secure. If you do need to perform security-related operations, you may want to encapsulate them in a separate process and use IPC. Extensive testing of your program is very hard, but critical to its security as well.

#### From admin perspective

Critical points are making sure recent security updates in the OS have been applied, that your server actually does run with lowest privileges possible and that it is unable to exhaust critical system resources (e.g. CPU, RAM, open file descriptors, open TCP connections etc).

Comment: Best andmost complete answer high hand, but you won't get correct answer/voting because you don't have 20k+ rep... SO at work.

Answer (score 4):

Opening a port, reading incoming bytes and storing them in a string is safe with Java. Just be prepared to get illegal or "malicious" content. Trivial example: an application uses the received bytes for database queries and someone sends "sql injection code"...

There's more risk with programming language where buffer overflow is possible. Then one *could* use the connection to inject and execute machine code - if the listening application is vulnerable.

Preventing is pretty easy: validate the input and drop every illegal message. Add some tests that send illegal content and check, if those inputs are properly rejected.

Comment: *"Opening a port, reading incoming bytes and storing them in a string is safe with Java"* - this is not true. There could be a bunch of vulnerabilities on the OS/network drivers themselves. You might argue "that's not Java", but well, you gotta pass through that, so it affects you anyway. You might mean there are no know vulnerabilities on the JVM, which is also false (check [String to Double conversion with Java bug](http://www.exploringbinary.com/java-hangs-when-converting-2-2250738585072012e-308/), which can easily DoS a server).

Comment: Sure, of course, that's true, ... but the question was about *What exactly can be exploited in a Java program* and *the biggest vulnerability is the program listening to the port*.

Comment: You still didn't mention anything about possible JVM and Java libraries vulnerabilities, which is directly related to the question.

Comment: Second question: *As the developer of the software, how can I prevent these vulnerabilities?* - you can't do anything against *those* issues except moving to another platform/programming language.

Comment: You're right, but "as the developer of the software" you can also help fix the bugs in open source software you're using as base so your software doesn't suffer from those same vulns ;)

Answer (score 3):

The vulnerabilities are in unauthorized usage of your program. Theoretically "bad guy" may perform reverse engineering of you wire protocol, understand how does your program work and make it to do "bad" things. For example if you program is able to delete files on disk when it receives delete command the bad guy may send this command with parameter `/`, so the program will remove all files from disk.

You can imagine yourself other scenarios.

This is the reason that system administrators do not like to open ports for any server but only for well known ones.

To prevent such scenario you should design your protocol well, use authentication mechanism and (probably) encryption of wire protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Another batch of attacks are DOS attacks.
This is not specific for java, but java IMO does not protect you against:
- Attacker can send huge/infinite input to crash your application.
- Attacker can send imput slowly to consume your resources.